# Heroku and Docker BuildKit

Tags: docker, heroku, docker-buildkit

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/build-docker-images-heroku-yml outlines how to build Docker images on Heroku.

However, it seems that Heroku runs a [very] old version of Docker because BuildKit doesn't work. I need BuildKit (works with Docker 18.09 or higher) to install a dependency from a private GitHub repo. Using `RUN --mount=ssh ...`, which is required to [attach SSH keys while building the image](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/build_enhancements/#using-ssh-to-access-private-data-in-builds), fails with

```
Dockerfile parse error line xx: Unknown flag: mount
```

and I wasn't able to resolve that (nope, adding `# syntax=...` to the top of the Dockerfile didn't work, same goes for `DOCKER_BUILDKIT=1` env variable).

How to setup Docker BuildKit on Heroku? Or is it really not possible? Does someone know what Docker version runs on Heroku?

Comment: @PURVESHPATEL I didn't, unfortunately.